# I get error rdr is not declared

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint

With this line of code

```
using (rdr as mysqldatareader = cmd.executereader())
```

I get an error saying rdr is not declared. When I remove the brackets so that it becomes

```
Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

I get error on this line `tmpObj.No = rdr("No").ToString()`saying No is not a member of the project.Form.Appdata and this line 
`tmpObj.Template = templa8` and Template is not a member of the project.Form.AppData. Note that I have already put this: `Private FPList As New List(Of AppData)` at the class level, as a member. Definitely I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

```
'THIS NEEDS TO BE AT THE CLASS-LEVEL, AS A MEMBER
'Private FPList As New List(Of AppData)
     Public Class AppData

     Public Sub Update()
        RaiseEvent OnChange()
    End Sub
    Public Event OnChange()
    Public FPList As New List(Of AppData)
    Public IsEventHandlerSucceeds As Boolean = True
    Public IsFeatureSetMatched As Boolean = False
    Public FalseAcceptRate As Integer = 0
    Public Sub Update()
        RaiseEvent OnChange()
    End Sub
    Public Event OnChange()
    Public FPList As New List(Of AppData)
    End Class



Private Sub Me_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles MyBase.Load
    Init()
    StartCapture()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM new_case_file"    
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection("**** "), _
       cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)

        conn.Open()
        Using (rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           FPList.Clear()
            While (rdr.Read())
                Dim tmpObj As New AppData
                tmpObj.No = rdr("No").ToString()

                Dim fpBytes As Byte() = rdr("FingerPrint")
                Using MemStream As New IO.MemoryStream(fpBytes)

                    Dim templa8 As New DPFP.Template()
                    templa8.DeSerialize(MemStream)
                    tmpObj.Template = templa8
                End Using

                FPList.Add(tmpObj)
            End While
            rdr.Close()
        End Using
    End Using 
End Sub
```

Comment: Post the code for `AppData`.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what you need to know.  You are attempting to assign a value to the "No" property of an object of type "AppData", but the "Appdata" class has no member called "No".

Comment: How do l write the code to correct this? I have been trying to resolve this but to know avail.

Answer (score 0):

You correct that error by adding the following to your AppData class

```
Private _No As String
Public Property No As String
    Get
        Return _No
    End Get
    Set(value as String)
        _No = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _Template As DPFP.Template
Public Property Template As DPFP.Template
    Get
        Return _Template
    End Get
    Set(value as DPFP.Template)
        _Template = value
    End Set
End Property
```

but that will not necessarily make your code work.